# Passing parameters to AsyncTask and changing them

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, parameter-passing

I have an AsyncTask that does something:

```
private class Task extends
        AsyncTask<Foo, Void, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Foo... params) {
        // send foo to server;
    }
}
```

In my main class I do something like:

```
new Task().execute(foo);
foo.setValue(0);
```

Will the value of foo in the AsyncTask background always be the old value? Or could it be that the value of foo is set to 0 before the AsyncTask executes its task?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The async task gets run on a different thread, communication between thread should be done through thread messaging using a handler. You can not change the value of a member of an async task like you are doing.

Here is a nice tutorial which is all about threads, asyn tasks and handlers: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html

And more examples using handlers: http://code.google.com/p/meneameandroid/source/search?q=handleMessage&origq=handleMessage&btnG=Search+Trunk, using an handler to perform animations: http://code.google.com/p/android-page-curl/source/browse/trunk/src/com/mystictreegames/pagecurl/PageCurlView.java

Comment: I don't want them to communicate. I want to send the value of foo to a server in a different thread (not stalling the application). But in mean time, can I set the value of foo to another value (in the main thread) to continue the main thread calculations with that new value without affecting the value passed to the AsyncTask?

Comment: But if you change the value in the thread and in the main thread at the same time you will get problems, if you want to access a shared variable you have to lock the acces using a synchroized block: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/synchronized.html.

Comment: Yes, but it's only changed in the main thread, not in the AsyncTask (it is just send to the server). Maybe I should just take a copy of foo...